# Change rcnn_resnet_101.config file in Tensorflow object-detection API for high resolution training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I am referring to: (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). My training set consists of labelled images with boxes exported in xml format for training. The dimentions of my input training images are min_dimension: 2976
max_dimension: 4464. By default the config file has min_dimension: 600
max_dimension: 1024. I am changing this to 2976x4464 please see below code to see the changed config file

```
# Faster R-CNN with Resnet-101 (v1) configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {


    #Specifying the keep_aspect_ratio_resizer follows the image resizing scheme 
    #described in the Faster R-CNN paper on page 6. In this case it always 
    #resizes an image so that the smaller edge is 600 pixels and if the longer
    #edge is greater than 1024 pixels, it resizes such that the longer edge is 
    #1024 pixels. The resulting image always has the same aspect ratio as the input image.

        min_dimension: 2976
        max_dimension: 4464
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet101'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .0003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000003
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_2017_11_08/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "data/object-detection.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "data/object-detection.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  num_epochs: 1
}
```

My question is what is first_stage_features_stride: 16?, do I need to change this because I changed dimensions of input training images in config file, also what else do I change in the code to suit the new dimensions of input Image. Do I need to make changes in train_config{} session of above code?